# Laravel ajax post returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to load some data via an AJAX request after selecting a value from a dropdown in textbox. However after selecting from the dropdown it's showing `500 (Internal Server Error)`. How do I solve it?

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$('#teacher').on('change',function(e){  
    var tech_id = $('#teacher option:selected').attr('value');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "{{url('ajaxteach')}}",
        data: {
            tech_id: tech_id
        },
        success: function(data) { 
            var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
            $('#credit_taken').val(json_obj.credit_taken); 
            $('#remaining_credit').val(json_obj.remaining_credit); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Here is my controller

```
public function get_teach(Request $request)
{
    $tech_id = $request::input(['tech_id']);      
    $teachers= \App\Teacher::where('teacher_id','=',$tech_id)->get();    
    return Response::json($teachers); 
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('ajaxteach', [
    'uses' => 'CourseController@get_teach',
    'as' => 'ajaxteach',
]);
```

Comment: Check the network response and see what the error is saying?

Comment: Is that a way to post your controller file?

Answer (score 0):

On jquery ajax call you pass

```
teach_id: teach_id
```

And controller looks at `tech_id` you also forgot `query()`, correct should be

```
$tech_id = $request::input(['teach_id']);      
$teachers= \App\Teacher::query()->where('teacher_id','=',$teach_id)->get();
```

Comment: Sorry Typo mistake.. Still getting same Error though!

Comment: I have added the query(), but nothing changed, still getting the same  error.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that:

`$request::input(['tech_id']);`

You have an object so You shouldn't get to it unstatic method in the static way. You can use `get()` method on `$request` object:

`$request->get('tech_id');`

So the whole controller method is:

```
public function get_teach(Request $request)
{
    $tech_id = $request->get('tech_id');      
    $teachers= \App\Teacher::where('teacher_id','=',$tech_id)->get();    
    return Response::json($teachers); 
}
```

Comment: If You get 500 and You're in dev enviroment than You can cheack the response of ajax (from server) for example in Chrome hit F12 and rerun the page. Then get to the network tab on chrome development tool and find the request that files (it's on the red). Click it and check the response message.

Comment: Thanks bro, your solution may not be given my Question's answer exactly but I got chance to know how to check the response and find the error. 
I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there were a couple of bits in your original function that looked like potential issues. Failing that, you'd need to post the details of the error.

```
public function get_teach(Request $request)
{
    $tech_id = $request -> tech_id;
    $teachers= \App\Teacher::where('teacher_id','=',$tech_id)->get();
    return response() -> json($teachers); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check you laravel.log (storage/logs/laravel.log).

By default, laravel uses 'id' as primary key.
If you are not using that, you should set on you App\Teacher model:

`class Teacher extends Eloquent {
    protected $primaryKey = 'teacher_id';
}`

So you can use in your controller:

`$teachers= \App\Teacher::find($tech_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this problem recently. You've added the header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' to your ajax request, as shown in your code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

but its value might be empty if you forgot to add the following code to your page head. Try to add this inside your head tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

This might work out.